# Multiprocessing in python with ZeroMQ

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq

My program takes arguments and according to these arguments I create 2 threads within this process. I have to run a few processes from terminal at the same time and also a thread in the process takes a user input. When I run them with with:
`python x.py args & python x.py args & ...` it does not even ask for the user input.

Can you give me any idea to handle this?

Comment: And where is the implementation code -- the MCVE? StackOverflow works on posting MCVE-formulated problem. You may rather update your post, so as to meet this StackOverflow standard policy and attract Community Members to review the MCVE posted.

Comment: It's true that posting some code may help. You can also clarify what you mean by "ask" for user input. Do the background processes fail to **display a prompt** that you expected to see? Or do they fail to **wait** for user input, instead proceeding with the following instructions as if they'd received (empty) input? (Or both?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a natural consequence of running a task in the background.  See the [bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the command in the background. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true). When job control is not active (see Job Control), the standard input for asynchronous commands, in the absence of any explicit redirections, is redirected from /dev/null.

Your answer is likely to redirect the information you want from somewhere else.  The simplest way is to write a file with the input you want for each function:

```
$ cat abcd > first
$ cat "Hello, this is a file" > second
$ python x.py < first & python x.py < second
```